# React Table Cell

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want to display a history record data  in a column  which I get after editing a model. But when I try to do so, I get multiple data in one cell when I have modified mutiple fields before hitting **Update button**

So my question is how to display each item in a new cell. I want to separate **Voltage, Year, Number** each in its cell with its data (New Value, Old Value)

**My Code**

```
const batteryHistoryCopy = batteryHistory.map(historyItem => { 

        const changedFieldsData = Object.entries(historyItem.changed_fields);
      
        return {    
            ...historyItem,
            history_date: moment(historyItem.history_date).format("LLL"),
            history_type: (()=>{
                switch (historyItem.history_type) {
                    case "~":
                        return "Update";
                    case "+": 
                        return "Addition";
                    case "-": 
                        return "Deletion";
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            })(),
            changed_fields: {
                actual_changed_field: changedFieldsData.map(item => capitalize(item[0])),
                old_value: changedFieldsData.map(item => item[1]["old_value"]),
                new_value: changedFieldsData.map(item => item[1]["new_value"])
            }
        }
    });

    const columns =  [
        {
            Header: 'History Type',
            accessor: 'history_type'
        },
        {
            Header: 'Modified By',
            accessor: 'history_user.username'
        },
        {
            Header: 'Modifed At',
            accessor: 'history_date',
            sortBy: "datetime"
        },  
        {
            Header: "Changed Fields Section",
            columns: [
                {
                    Header: "Actual Changed Field",
                    accessor: "changed_fields.actual_changed_field",
                    // Cell: d => console.log(d.original.changed_fields)
                },
                {
                    Header: "Old Value",
                    accessor: "changed_fields.old_value"
        
                },
                {
                    Header: "New Value",
                    accessor: "changed_fields.new_value"
                }
            ]
        },

    ]

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <ReactTable
                sortable
                style={styles.batteryHistoryTab}
                data={batteryHistoryCopy}
                columns={columns}
                loading={loading.fetchBatteryHistory}
            />
        </Fragment>
    )

}
```

1. **React Table**
   [image]
2. **Data in Google Chrome Dev Tools**

I logged this on the console by using the **Cell** : d  => console.log(d => d.original.changed_fields)

[image]

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @ChristianFritz, I have updated the question with  a screenshot and code.